# Producing a map with barplots using geom_subplot2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a map with barplots for each state. I used geom_subplot2d. I am having a couple of issues and I was hoping somebody can help fix them

- The border color I want it to be black but it is red no matter what value I use.
- The color of the legend items (barplot) is also absorbed by each state. Is there a way that it can be separate?

Here is the code that produces the diagram:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = total, 
               aes(x = x, y = y, group = region, colour = "black", 
                   fill = cut(eval(as.symbol(var1)), 10)))  +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")

testplot <- p + 
  geom_subplot2d(aes(long, lat, subplot = geom_bar(aes(yy, ..count.., fill = yy))),
                 bins = c(25,20), ref = NULL, width = rel(0.5), data = simdat) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlGn")

print(testplot)
```

[image]

Comment: The first issue is solved by putting the `col` statement ouside of `aes`. Inside `aes` are only those aesthetics that you are mapping to a variable.

Comment: I suspect you can't (easily) solve problem two, as it's a design philosophy of `ggplot2` to always map only one thing to an aesthetic.

Comment: Yes! The color changed once I moved outside aes. Since I can define borders for both barplot and states then changing the base color for states is not such a big concern.